# What does "pleaseverify" tag mean in contributing to open source projects?

Tags: github, open-source

This my first time trying to contribute to open source projects. I'm wondering what it means when there is a "pleaseverify" label. Does that mean the team wants someone with experience to verify the bug first before someone else works on it? Or does it mean that I, as a new contributor, have to verify that the bug exist before working on it?

PS. I have googled but cannot find information on the topic.

Comment: You mean a label on an issue? Those mean whatever the project team wants them to mean. Labels can be created with any name for any purpose. There's a good chance that their contributing guidelines will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

First, [creating a label on GitHub](http://pleaseverify) is not linked to some naming convention: you can use any name you want.

Each project has its own convention.
[Here, for instance](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1789#issuecomment-320451666):

> I've added the `pleaseverify` tag just so that we can track or ask for more input from other developers/users that are having the same problem.